# Under what conditions is the system clock running?

Tags: power, system-clock, ntp

The Raspberry Pi has no battery powered hardware clock, so it needs to fetch time via NTP and store it via `fake-hwclock` to not start at 1970 again after a power-loss. When the device is running the CPU keeps track of time.

**How is "running" defined here?**

Examples of what I mean follow. When I do

```
sudo reboot
```

where the CPU does not power down, does the clock stop for some seconds or does it even get reset? When I do

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

but do *not* pull the power cord (PWR LED still on), does the clock continue running or does it stop or does it reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you shut down properly, the time is saved and reloaded on next boot. On reboot you should only lose a few seconds if no NTP is available.

Comment: So, the time is only running when the operating system is actually running? CPU having power, but no operating system running, is not enough?

Comment: I haven't actually checked the Raspbian code, but the clock on most computer systems is driven by a periodic interrupt which increments a counter. Without an OS to service the interrupts nothing happens.